# How to start with Power BI. Using Sisense as of now

Tags: powerbi, analytics, sisense

May be this is stupid question.

I am using Sisense for the analytics. Back end is SQL Server. Now we are thinking to move to Power BI. When I search for Power BI I see different versions. 1) desktop power bi 2) azure power bi.

Does both are same ? I can search for tutorial on google but I want some perfect direction. I want the similar kind feature that's sisense have.

Thank you.

Comment: You use desktop to create the report and use the service to share it in your organisation.

Comment: Thanks @Jon,  I got your point. I need to create the report in desktop and use service to publish it. Is it possible to do it locally ? Does Power BI support all the functionality that Sisense support ? any idea ?